# Execute Java Application from Command Line without package or class specification?

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

I'm in class, and no, before I begin, I don't need anyone to do my homework.  The program is written, but the instructor said he grades using a scripted test bed, and the program (a simple Palindrome test, I'm a noob) must be executable as per his specifications or his test bed won't be able to run it, and if it doesn't run it, he isn't gonna try it manually and I fail the assignment (charmer I know.)  Basically, his requirements are this:

There cannot be a package declaration in the application.

It must be executable from command line with simply this:

```
java Palindrome
```

that's it.  When I navigate to the directory the file lives in and try that, it gives me `could not find or load main class Palindrome`.  Looking that error up, there's lots of solutions that include leading - paramters or a fully qualified class name.  I can't use either of those, because if `java Palindrome` doesn't launch it, I get a 0.

Can anyone tell me how to get it to run without any parameters or fully qualified class names?  Just `java Palindrome`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute `java <filename>` it tries to find the file in the current directory. If it's not found, it returns an error saying `could not find or load main class`.

So, in your case, you are either executing java command from different directory or you haven't compiles the class. For the former, you can specify the class file path with `-cp` argument to command (e.g. `java -cp FULLPATH CopyFile`), for the latter case, you need to compile the class with `javac` first and then, execute it.

Comment: It's the compile step I missed then.  Which do I target with the compile command (using netbeans) the parent project folder, or just the Palindrome.java file that I wrote in?

Comment: Try `javac Palindrome.java`

Comment: so I compiled it successfully, and now there's a Palindrome.class file.  now when I run `java Palindrome` from that directory it still says `could not find or load main class Palindrome`. What am I missing?

Comment: @user3066571 Give `java -cp . Palindrome` a try. It sets the classpath to the current directory, and since `java` looks for the classes on the classpath (not the current directory by default) it should run correctly.